# How can I create Local Loopback on Linux (RedHat or Debian)?

Tags: ethernet, localhost, tcpip, gigabit-ethernet, loopback

How can I do the same on Linux (RedHat or Debian)?

I need to create local loopback as shown herein: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/topic-map/ethernet-fast-and-gigabit-loopback-testing.html#id-11863133

> Configure a Local Loopback Action
>
> To configure a local loopback without physically connecting the
>   transmit port to the receive port, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In configuration mode, go to the following hierarchy level:
>
>    [edit]
>
>    user@host# edit interfaces interface-name (fastether-options |
>      gigether-options)
> 2. Configure the local loopback:
>
>    [edit interfaces interface-name (fastether-options | gigether-options)]
>
>    user@host# set loopback

Comment: What precisely do you "need" this for, and why is the `lo` interface not sufficient? Linux and JunOS are so different that 'loopback' probably won't _do_ the same thing.

Comment: @grawity Ultimately, I want to test Physical 1Gbit Ethernet Loopback , and I want to understand what commands to perform on Linux (RedHat or Debian) for this.